# Autofac lazy property injection

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm trying to inject business logic implementations into web API base controller. Somehow property in base controller is always `null`.

Also how can I do lazy injection?

**Startups.cs**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<ViewBusinessLogic>().As<IViewBusinessLogic>().
        PropertiesAutowired();
    containerBuilder.Populate(services);

    var container = containerBuilder.Build();

    return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

**Interface, implementation and base controller:**

```
public interface IViewBusinessLogic
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> GetView(Guid viewId);
}

public class ViewBusinessLogic : BusinessLogic, IViewBusinessLogic
{
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetView(Guid viewId)
    {
        return new List<dynamic>
        {
            new { Test = "Test1" },
            new { Test = "Test2" }
        };
    }
}

public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IViewBusinessLogic ViewBusinessLogic { get; }
}
```

Comment: **This is not an Autofac question, it's an ASP.NET Core question.** The property injection won't work in any other DI provider without `AddControllersAsServices` either - hence my title edit. Downvoted question due to incorrect title and refusal to update to more accurate title.

Answer (score 2):

Controllers aren't resolved by the DI framework by default. You need to add `AddControllerAsServices` to have them be resolved by the DI of your choice.

From [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4855#issuecomment-225364069):

> > Hi,
> >
> > Maybe I'm wrong but as I tested deeply (and checked Mvc source code), Controllers are not resolved from `IServiceProvider`, but only constructor arguments of them are resolved from `IServiceProvider`.
> >
> > Is that by design? I'm very suprised. Because, I'm using a different DI framework which supports property injection. And I can not use property injection since Controller instances are not requested from `IServiceProvider`.
>
> Have you added `AddControllersAsServices` in your Startup (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ab76f743f4ee537939b69bdb9f79bfca35398545/test/WebSites/ControllersFromServicesWebSite/Startup.cs#L37)

The example above quoted for future reference.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var builder = services
        .AddMvc()
        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager => manager.ApplicationParts.Clear())
        .AddApplicationPart(typeof(TimeScheduleController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
        {
            manager.ApplicationParts.Add(new TypesPart(
              typeof(AnotherController),
              typeof(ComponentFromServicesViewComponent),
              typeof(InServicesTagHelper)));

            manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new AssemblyMetadataReferenceFeatureProvider());
        })

        // This here is important
        .AddControllersAsServices()
        .AddViewComponentsAsServices()
        .AddTagHelpersAsServices();

    services.AddTransient<QueryValueService>();
    services.AddTransient<ValueService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

As for the second part of your question: I don't think it's possible to have lazy instantiation via IoC container at all. Best fit for you is to create a factory class and inject the factory rather than the concrete service.

But usually you don't need lazy instantiation anyways, the instantiation of services **should be fast**. If it's not, you probably doing some funky stuff in the constructor (connecting somewhere, or doing other long running operations), which is an anti-pattern.