# Hangfire ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

Having trouble scheduling/enqueuing an MVC action with Hangfire (1.6.5)
(Custom IServices works just fine..)

***No service for type 'Controllers.MyController' has been registered.***

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult RenderViewToString() 
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Test() 
    {
        //Attempt 1
        Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue<MyController>(c => c.RenderViewToString());

        //Attempt 2
        Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => c.RenderViewToString());

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note, that it's not called MVC6 anymore. The correct name is "ASP.NET Core MVC" with version 1.0

Comment: There's a much bigger issue here, and that is why you would want to use a controller for this sort of thing? For a start a background task will not return anything. Secondly, you shouldn't be relying on controller/request context to be available to you inside Hangfire tasks either.

Comment: @DavidG I know this is not optimal. I am using MVC to render a view to PDF. I need the ControllerContext for that.. Not aware of any other way.

Comment: What are you using to generate the PDF? You cannot have access to the controller context, there is none for background tasks.

Comment: @DavidG http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string

Comment: Er, that's a string not a PDF - very different things!

Comment: Yes, but that is what my question is all about. I am using Prince to render the string to a pdf. Works great. That is not the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a nice way to do this. You may be better off converting the view to a string and the passing that to the background task to render as PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, controllers aren't being registered with the dependency injection system in ASP.NET Core. You need to explicitly call `AddControllersAsService` to register them, as explained in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4855#issuecomment-225364069):

> > Hi,
> >
> > Maybe I'm wrong but as I tested deeply (and checked Mvc source code), Controllers are not resolved from `IServiceProvider`, but only constructor arguments of them are resolved from `IServiceProvider`.
> >
> > Is that by design? I'm very suprised. Because, I'm using a different DI framework which supports property injection. And I can not use property injection since Controller instances are not requested from `IServiceProvider`.
>
> Have you added `AddControllersAsServices` in your Startup (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ab76f743f4ee537939b69bdb9f79bfca35398545/test/WebSites/ControllersFromServicesWebSite/Startup.cs#L37)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39556583) to a related question for an example and more details.

Comment: Thank you! That takes me one step further. Now the controllers dependencies does not seem to get activated.. A alot of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Any ideas?

Comment: My bad. HttpContext does not get activated. For obvious reasons.. Have to work around that.