# How to manage EFCore DbContext life in ASP.NET Core web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm implementing 3-tier architecture, and **my question is:** Where should I call `SaveChanges();` (if applicable)? Where should I create and commit transaction? Please read the whole question.

In the code below I have only "read" operation, but you'll get the idea of the architecture. I'm struggling with the decision, but I came out with two options:

1. Reference EFCore in the `Core` project. Inject DbContext into `Service` class and via method inject it to the Data layer. Like this:

   ```
   public class ItemService
   {
       private MyContext _ctx;
       private readonly IItemData _itemData;   

       public ItemService(IItemData itemData)
       {
           _itemData = itemData;
       }   

       public void InjectCtx(MyContext ctx)
       {
           _ctx = ctx;
           _itemData.InjectCtx(_ctx);
       }   

       public void Operation(int itemId)
       {
           using (var transaction = _ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
           {
               //Do something  

               _ctx.SaveChanges();
               transaction.Commit();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create an interface in the `Core` for Unit of work object. Which will have SaveChanges and Transaction, Commit methods. Then implement them in the Data layer and call accordingly in the `Service` class.

**Here is the code.** I have 3 projects:

- Infrstructure (Data) - *references Core and EFCore*
- Core (Business logic) - *no dependencies*
- Web API (MVC project) - *references Core, Data and EFCore*

**- Core (no dependencies, not even a reference to EFCore):**

```
public class ItemDto
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IItemData
{
    Task<ItemDto> GetItem(int itemId);
}

public class ItemService
{
    private readonly IItemData _itemData;

    public ItemService(IItemData itemData)
    {
        _itemData = itemData;
    }

    public async Task<ItemDto> GetItem(int itemId)
    {
        return await _itemData.GetItem(itemId);
    }
}
```

**- Data (reference to Core project and EFCore)**

```
   public class ItemData : IItemData
    {
        private readonly MyContext _ctx;

        public ItemData(MyContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public async Task<ItemDto> GetItem(int itemId)
        {
            var item = await _ctx.Items
                .Where(i => i.ItemId == itemId)
                .Select(row => new ItemDto()
                {
                    ItemId = row.ItemId,
                    Name = row.ItemName
                })
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            return item;
        }
    }
```

**- Web API:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ItemService _itemService;

    public ItemsController(ItemService itemService)
    {
        _itemService = itemService;
    }

    [HttpGet("{itemId}")]
    public async Task<ItemDto> Get(int itemId)
    {
        return await _itemService.GetItem(itemId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us where and how you're bootstrapping the Context. The DI Container should be managing the life cycle of the context. Also how long of a lifetime do you want the context to live? Per request?

Comment: @Train thx, DI container is built in ASP.NET Core Web api. It Startup class you configure it. There is a new instance per request.

Comment: I would vote for your second solution. But I would move the interface and its implementation to the infrastructure project. Persistence is no responsibility of the business logic

Answer (score 0):

If you really feel you need transactions, I would try to handle them 'above' your services, so that those ones are not responsible for handling them.

A way of doing this can be:

- Use a scoped `DbContext`.
- When a request starts or a service methods is invoked, create a transaction with `Database.BeginTransaction()`.
- Your service layer invokes your data layer and handles the business logic.
- Your data layer applies `.SaveChanges()` wherever it's needed.
- When a request ends or a service method invocation end, either run `transaction.Commit()` or `transaction.Rollback()`.

A way of achieving those transactions creations/commits/rollbacks without making your services responsble of it can be using [filters, middlewares](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-middleware-as-mvc-filters-in-asp-net-core-1-1/) or [interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290006/interception-on-net-core-2-0-web-api-controller-by-using-autofac).